# python form setfocus

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am working with python plugins for qgis.I have two form designed **DlgQuerybuilder.py** and **DlgDbError.py**.I am calling **DlgDbError.py** from **DlgQuerybuilder.py** as follows:

```
except DbConnection.DbError, e:
       QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
       DlgDbError.showError(e, self)
       return
```

my DlgDbError.py contains:

```
def showError(e, parent):

    global w 
    w = DlgDbError(e,parent)
    w.show()
```

But when **DlgDbError.py** is shown,it is shown below **DlgQuerybuilder.py** form.

[image]

Does form has setfocus property??I tried googling around,but no success.Even if i set **focuspolicy** to **Clickfocus** ,it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the QWidget methods `activateWindow`, `raise` and `setFocus` in [the Qt docs](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QWidget.html). 
Note also that in PyQt, `raise` is renamed to `raise_`.